Hazelcast caching provider - How to set the config smart routing programmatically?
I updated the Hazelcast version of my java project from 3.12.X to 5.3.5. However when I run the application locally I receive this error:
[WARNING ] _hzinstance_jcache_shared [dev] [5.3.5] Exception during initial connection to [127.0.0.1]:5703: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.io.IOException: Connection refused: no further information to address /127.0.0.1:5703
When looking up the error, it seems like I need to set the smart routing to FALSE. I am wondering how I can set it up programmatically when creating the config as a MutableConfiguration ?
Here is a snippet of my code:
@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {
  // Get the default cache service.
  final CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
  final CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();

  // Configure the cache.
  final MutableConfiguration<Integer, MyCustomResponse> config = new MutableConfiguration<>();
  config.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(HOURS, 2)));
  config.setTypes(Integer.class, MyCustomResponse.class);

  // Now create the cache.
  Cache<Integer, MyCustomResponse> myCache = cacheManager.createCache("myCache", config);
}

I have tried solving my error by setting the smart routing to FALSE: config.getNetworkConfig().setSmartRouting(false)

MutableConfiguration is used to configure JCache. You can set timeout duration of a cache just like your example.
However, how the client connects to a cluster is set by ClientConfig. You need to configure a ClientConfig bean, like the example below:
@Bean
public ClientConfig clientConfig() {
  ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
  ClientNetworkConfig networkConfig = clientConfig.getNetworkConfig();
  networkConfig.setSmartRouting(true);
  // other configuration for the client
  return clientConfig;
}


Does it mean the error is occurring due to the timeout duration of the cache? Or I need to have the ClientConfiguration set like in your example in order to solve the error?

I am not sure why you need smart routing, but if you need it you need to configure it like my example. In general any connection related configuration needs to go into ClientConfig and cache related configuration needs to go into MutableConfiguration

because otherwise I don't know how to solve my error. As I have been googling around and setting the smart routing will solve my error I would guess? Or do you know any other solution?

I can also mention that I only want to use the Jcache to cache calls, nothing else. I also do not have any hazelcast.xml defined or such
